# Displaying multiple images of a product in a Datalist Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a project in which i have to display products like Ecommerce website (with sliding multiple images).

There i want to display multiple images of each product within a Cell.

I have 2 tables named Product_Master & Product_Images as follows:-

**Product_Master :-**

**Id Pcode Pname MRP DP**

1 1234 Samsung Mobile 20000 18000

2 2345 Mi Mobile 15000 14000

3 3456 Realme Mobile 12000 10000

4 4567 Nokia Mobile 9000 8000

**Product_Images :-**

**Id Pcode ImgName**

1 1234 Samsung1.jpg

2 1234 Samsung2.jpg

3 1234 Samsung3.jpg

4 1234 Samsung4.jpg

5 2345 Mi1.jpg

6 2345 Mi2.jpg

7 2345 Mi3.jpg

8 3456 Realme1.jpg

9 3456 Realme2.jpg

10 4567 Nokia1.jpg

11 4567 Nokia2.jpg

12 4567 Nokia3.jpg

**After joing these tables I got 12 rows in datatable**

**Product_Images.Id--Product_Master.Pcode--Product_Images.ImgName--Product_Master.Pname--Product_Master.MRP--Product_Master.DP**

1 1234 Samsung1.jpg Samsung Mobile 20000 18000

2 1234 Samsung2.jpg Samsung Mobile 20000 18000

3 1234 Samsung3.jpg Samsung Mobile 20000 18000

4 1234 Samsung4.jpg Samsung Mobile 20000 18000

5 2345 Mi1.jpg Mi Mobile 15000 14000

6 2345 Mi2.jpg Mi Mobile 15000 14000

7 2345 Mi3.jpg Mi Mobile 15000 14000

8 3456 Realme1.jpg Realme Mobile 12000 10000

9 3456 Realme2.jpg Realme Mobile 12000 10000

10 4567 Nokia1.jpg Nokia Mobile 9000 8000

11 4567 Nokia2.jpg Nokia Mobile 9000 8000

12 4567 Nokia3.jpg Nokia Mobile 9000 8000

Now I want to display 4 Cells for products which contains

- **Product Name on Label**
- **Product Code on Label**
- **Multiple Images with slider in Repeater or any other control/**
- **Dp on Label**
- **MRP on Label.**

Here I am Attaching my Code for binding the data with datalist & its repeater. After appyling the given code I got 12 Cells which contains Same Information of products with different images.

But I want to show each Product Information with its multiple images as slider  in a Single cells. Means i want to display 4 cells in which product image can slide...

**Please help me out.**

I hope you will understand my concern....

Thanks

```
<asp:DataList ID="DatListProduct" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DatListProduct_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblProdName" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" Text='<%# Eval("Pnamae")%>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblProdPcode" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" Text='<%# Bind("Pcode") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Repeater ID="InnerRepeaterCourseResults" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="ImgProdImg" runat="server" Height="220px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imgname", "~Gallery/{0}")%>' Width="220px" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:Label ID="lblProdDP" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Large" Text='<%# Bind("DP") %>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblProdMRP" runat="server" Font-Bold="false" Font-Strikeout="true" Font-Size="Medium" Text='<%# Bind("MRP") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
    Private Sub DataListProducts()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Product_Images.Id, 
        Product_Master.Pcode, Product_Images.Imgname, 
        Product_Master.Pname, 
        Product_Master.MRP, Product_Master.DP FROM Product_Master INNER 
        JOIN Product_Images ON Product_Master.Pcode = 
        Product_Images.Pcode", con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim dtp As New DataTable()
        dtp.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(5) {New 
        DataColumn("Id",GetType(Integer)), 
        New DataColumn("Pcode", GetType(String)), 
        New DataColumn("Pname", GetType(String)), 
        New DataColumn("MRP", GetType(Decimal)), 
        New DataColumn("DP", GetType(Decimal)), 
        New DataColumn("Imgname", GetType(String))})
        For i = 0 To (foundRows.Count - 1)
            dtp.Rows.Add(foundRows(i)("Id"), foundRows(i)("Pcode"), 
            foundRows(i)("Pname"), foundRows(i)("MRP"), foundRows(i) 
            ("DP"), foundRows(i)("Imgname"))
        Next
        Session("dtp") = dtp
        DatListProduct.DataSource = dtp
        DatListProduct.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DatListProduct_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As 
    DataListItemEventArgs)
        Dim dtp As New DataTable()
        dtp.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(5) {New DataColumn("Id", 
        GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("Pcode", GetType(String)), New 
        DataColumn("Pname", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("MRP", 
        GetType(Decimal)), New DataColumn("DP", GetType(Decimal)), New 
        DataColumn("Imgname", GetType(String))})
        dtp = Session("dtp")
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = 
        ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
              Dim Pcode As String = 
              (TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("lblProdPcode"), Label)).Text
              Dim InnerRepeaterCourseResults As Repeater = 
              TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("InnerRepeaterCourseResults"), 
              Repeater)
              InnerRepeaterCourseResults.DataSource = dtp.[Select]("Pcode=" & 
              Pcode & "").CopyToDataTable()
              InnerRepeaterCourseResults.DataBind()
       End If
    End Sub
```